# Android : Making Listview full screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-viewpager, android-relativelayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
 tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/location_edittext"
    android:id="@+id/locationEditext"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#999"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp" />


<com.example.ravi_gupta.slider.ViewPagerCustomDuration
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:layout_weight="0.5">
</com.example.ravi_gupta.slider.ViewPagerCustomDuration>

<ListView
    android:layout_weight="0.50"
    android:layout_below="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:id="@+id/shopListview" />
```

This is my code in activity.main I, all I want is that when I scroll the listview it take all the space in the layout hiding viewpager and editext and when I scroll back it shows both of them, I don't know how this can be possible, Either I should use Relative layout or some Other method

Comment: you have given weight to listview and height also why so?

Comment: I am trying to display listview either by height ot by weight but this solution seems not working

Comment: if you are giving weight then there is no need of height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply depend on the layout. Modify your code and look at `setVisibility` method @ [setVisibility of View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)).
For example, if that method is set to `GONE` to EditText UI, then that UI is completely hidden as if it was never shown. And then of course, you should set it to `VISIBLE` when appropriate.